# Power BI + MySQL - Unexpected error: Connection must be valid and open

Tags: mysql, connection, powerbi

When trying to manipulate (pivot a column) appended MySQL queries, I get

**"Unexpected error: Connection must be valid and open" message.**

The weird thing is that even though individual queries (consisting of this year's months)are working AND append with first six months of the year is working, for the last months it does not. Connection type and settings have not been changed. Connection was made with MySQL database.

I have no idea how to solve this. If you need any other detail from, please ask.

Comment: are you firing all queries from the same connection and from same window?

Comment: Yes. Everything is the same.